# Default value with two sets of parentheses instead of one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have an `int` field, and I set the default value as `(0)`, which works, but I've seen people doing it like this instead `((0))`,why?

Comment: Very old question, but I just noticed a pattern regarding double vs. single parentheses. I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53303759/1089416).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`((0))` is how it will appear within the catalog views or if you generate a script in SSMS. So I think when you see that it's most likely a generated script and not hand-written that way from scratch.

That said, there is nothing different between `(0)`, `((0))` or even `(((((((((((((0)))))))))))))` ... assuming I counted right, extra parentheses don't change the meaning, just readability.

Comment: Ahhh.. I always thought people just did it like that, but that makes sense, I suppose.. hehe.. Thanks again Aaron, nice to see you again. :)

Comment: Are we controlling the machines or are they controlling us?  To discover my own answers to this question, I searched SO for the deeper meaning of the multiple parenthesis when defining a SQL default value and found that while there is no deeper meaning I can derive great satisfaction by defining default values this way from now on:  (((((((((((((0)))))))))))))

Comment: Seems in 2014 and 2017 at least the parentheses are not needed at all https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823899/661584

Comment: @MemeDeveloper I don’t think they were ever needed for single values, it’s just the way they are stored/presented in the metadata.

Comment: @AaronBertrand indeed perhaps they never were, but the GUI generates them and personally (over the last 14 years) I'm not sure I've ever noticed a script without at least single parentheses for default values - so for me it was  a surprise to find they are actually unnecessary. (unless I am missing something) i.e. there is no difference between (0), ((0)) or even 0  - now I know which I will be using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simply

```
0
```

i.e. no parentheses at all, as per the SQL server documentation. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823899/661584