# Default value for column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a table in SQL say `mytable`. I've taken one column of type bit, as soon as i try to set the default value of that column using sql query like this

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR IsDeleted
```

I get this value `((0))` as default value in column properties as soon as i open the designer for that table.

Why I'm getting those extra brackets in default value and how can i set default value for other three columns in one go, assume other three column names to be `col1, col2, col3`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server default values: why with one or two parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911953/sql-server-default-values-why-with-one-or-two-parentheses)

Comment: found answer on the above link.. @Nadeem_MK thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ((0)) and (0) will evaluate to the same result, it is stored as such internally, so there is nothing to really overcome, just a visibility issue.

Using SQL SERVER, if you want to return a default value when a column is null, instead of altering the table, you can simply use the `ISNULL` function;

```
SELECT ISNULL(col1, 0)
      ,ISNULL(col2, 0) 
      ,ISNULL(col3, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is an alternative approach and also doesn't provide the reason for those extra brackets in column properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT default_val DEFAULT N'SANDNES' FOR col1;
```